# Indirect band gap and additional momentum?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

For indirect band gaps, an electron needs both energy and momentum in order to be excited from the conduction band.

I am not sure I understand the momentum requirement. What does it mean physically?
We need to "push" the electron forwards? Won't that be equivalent to just shining light onto it and let it recoil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that light has almost no momentum to give to the electrons in the solid (one usually makes the assupmtion of $k=0$). The dispersion relation for light is extremely steep because of the light speed ($E=ck$).

So the electron has to get (or give) some momentum to make the indirect transition. This is typically achieved through interactions with other excitations, most commonly with phonons. In such a case, a phonon with the required momentum gets annihilated and the electron takes that amount of momentum making the transition possible.

Comment: does it mean that you have to physically give a push to the material?

Comment: No, this is done through momentum carrying excitations in the crystal.

Comment: What does it mean in practise? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Hope it's a bit more clarified in my update.

Comment: But I thought a phonon was basically an oscillation in the crystal -  so to create it,  I exert a force on it for some time?

Comment: Phonons are, basically, always there. No need of exerting any force, temperature does the work.

Comment: ok, thanks! So basically you need a phonon and a photon at the same time? which is not very probable?